# Why do C++ constructors called from inside another constructor not modify class variables?

Tags: c++

Why do Constructors called directly from another constructor not modify class variables in C++?

For instance in the following code evenNum() is called but the val class variable is not modified. Therfore it prints 0 (the default value) and not 2 as expected.

```
#include <iostream>

class evenNum {
  public:
    int val;
    evenNum(){
      this->val = 2;
    }
    evenNum(int var)
    {
      if(var%2==0){
        this->val = var;
      }else{
        evenNum();
      }
    }
};

int main() {
  evenNum e(7);
  std::cout << e.val;
}
```

Comment: Because constructors create new instances - they don't modify existing ones. You might want to read up on constructor delegation.

Comment: You cannot "call" constructors in C++. There's no syntax for that. Constructors are always invoked implicitly for you (in specific contexts that trigger constructor invocation). Your `evenNum();` is not a "constructor call", as you seem to incorrectly believe. It is a cast in functional notation. While it does invoke the constructor internally, this cast has no effect on your object, which is exactly what you observed.

Comment: Unfortunately for novice programmers in C++ many things have different meanings  in different context. In this case `evenNum();` in this context means "create temporary of type `evenNum`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
    evenNum();
```

creates a temporary object. It does nothing to the object being constructed.

You can either use a delegating construtor or set the value of the member variable directly.

```
evenNum(int var) : evenNum()
{
  if(var%2==0){
    this->val = var;
  }
}
```

or

```
evenNum(int var)
{
  if(var%2==0){
    this->val = var;
  }else{
    this->val = 2;
  }
}
```

Using a delegating constructor is better. It expresses the intent clearly and reduces code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Your second constructor (the one with a parameter) does not call the first one (the one without parameters, i.e. the default construtor). Hence, the data member is not set in advance.

In C++, to call the default constructor, you need to specify the call after the method signature. Write:

```
evenNum(int var) : evenNum()
{ ...
}
```

Note that - unlike in other programming languages like, for example, java, constructors cannot be called from inside the function body. So `evenNum()` in the function body does not call a constructor but creates an (unused) temporary object:

```
evenNum(int var)
{
    evenNum();  // a new object is created (distinct from "this"), and discarded then.
    ...
}
```